# Trouble Installing Arduino on Netbeans in Ubuntu 11

Tags: netbeans, arduino

I am a complete noob to Arduino trying to make my first program.  I have Netbeans installed and I wanted to do my first Arduino program using Netbeans.  I found the following site that has some step-by-steps.  http://java.dzone.com/news/arduino-development-using

I am using NetBeans 7 on a Fresh install of Ubuntu 11.   I have been going step-by-step through the site.

My first hint that there is a problem is that the code Assist isn't working at all.
My next problem is that when I compile the default main.pde I get the following error:

`fatal error: WProgram.h: No such file or directory` in

`cat main.pde >> applet/ArduinoTest1.cpp
/usr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w       -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=18 -I/home/tmonteit/arduino-0018/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/home/tmonteit/arduino-0018/libraries -mmcu=atmega328p applet/ArduinoTest1.cpp -o applet/ArduinoTest1.o
applet/ArduinoTest1.cpp:1:22: fatal error: WProgram.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [applet/ArduinoTest1.o] Error 1`

When I troubleshoot similar problems online it seems that you have to make sure that you are using the correct library.

To install I used `apt-get install librxtx-java arduino-core arduino`
And then I downloaded `arduino-1.0`

How do I know if I have the correct libraries or setup?

Is there a proper way to get the right version of these libraries and arduino that will work with NetBeans?

Is there an easy fix?

Answer (score 1):

Since the version used in the guide you are using (Arduino 0018) there have been several library changes (mostly in Arduino 1.0 and notably the renaming of `WProgram.h` to `Arduino.h`).

To accommodate these changes the `main.pde` file will need to change to:

```
#define __AVR_ATmega328P__

#include <binary.h>
#include <HardwareSerial.h>
#include <pins_arduino.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <wiring_private.h>
#include <EEPROM/EEPROM.h>

void setup()
{

}

void loop()
{

}
```

Also, `pins_arduino.h` has moved from `hardware/arduino/cores/arduino` to `hardware/arduino/variants/standard` so you'll need to add this to your include path.